# How to set up Kubernetes ClusterRole binding to give `view` access to a service account for all namespaces

Tags: kubernetes

I set up a service account and a cluster role binding to give `view` access to a pod for all namespaces:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: mine-user
  namespace: mine
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: mine-rolebinding
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: mine-user
  namespace: mine
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: view
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

I try to list `deployments` using *curl*:

```
curl --cacert ${CACERT} --header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" -X GET ${APISERVER}/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/mine/deployments
```

But I get an error:

```
"deployments.apps is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:mine:mine-user\" cannot list resource \"deployments\" in API group \"apps\" in the namespace \"mine\""
```

The Role Binding exists though:

```
kubectl -n mine describe clusterrolebinding/mine-rolebinding
Name:         mine-rolebinding
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Role:
  Kind:  ClusterRole
  Name:  view
Subjects:
  Kind  Name               Namespace
  ----  ----               ---------
  User  mine-user          mine
```

I also get the same error while using a custom cluster role:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: mine-role
rules:
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  resources: ["deployments"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
```

```
$ kubectl -n mine describe clusterrolebinding/mine-rolebinding2
Name:         mine-rolebinding2
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Role:
 Kind:  ClusterRole
 Name:  mine-role
Subjects:
 Kind  Name               Namespace
 ----  ----               ---------
 User  mine-user          mine
$ kubectl -n mine describe clusterrole/mine-role
Name:         mine-role
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
PolicyRule:
 Resources         Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
 ---------         -----------------  --------------  -----
 deployments.apps  []                 []              [get list watch]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you created `ServiceAccount` and you are trying to create `ClusterRoleBinding` with `subjects.kind: User` and passing name of this `ServiceAccount`. It is not going to work.

Please change `subjects.kind` to `ServiceAccount` 
and remove `subjects.apiGroup` in your `ClusterRoleBinding`.

or just apply this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: mine-user
  namespace: mine
---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: mine-role
rules:
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  resources: ["deployments"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]

---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: mine-rolebinding
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: mine-user
  namespace: mine
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: mine-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

You can read more in [kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#referring-to-subjects) on how to refer to subjects in RoleBinding or ClusterRoleBinding.

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

you need also to define a role.
if you want to have a read right on deployments, you should first check on which apigroup "deployments" belong to:

kubectl api-resources
deployments    deploy       apps                           true         Deployment

-->belong to "apps" group

so role should look something like this:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: mine
  name: mine-rolebinding
rules:
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  resources: ["deployments"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

you can check the rights you have with the auth command:

```
kubectl auth can-i watch deployments --namespace mine --as mine-user
yes
```

more infos :

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/

Comment: Nope, doesn't work either. I edited the description.

Comment: you should define roleBindings,mapped to the namespace mine and not clusterroleBindings. also you should define Roles,and not ClusterRoles,as in my comment from above

Comment: But I need ClusterRole to access any namespace.